# Find and replace without backsearching

Tags: r

R novice here with what is probably a silly/ simple question.

I am trying to use R to find and replace within a vector "census.new" (basically trying to use R to do what excel does with find/ replace). However, because the original data (what I am searching for) overlaps partially with what I am trying to replace, I am ending up with some funky results.

I am trying to replace 2 with 2008b, 3 with 2009a, etc.

```
census.new<-sub("2","2008b", census.new, fixed=TRUE)
census.new<-sub("3","2009a", census.new, fixed=TRUE)
census.new<-sub("4","2009b", census.new, fixed=TRUE)
census.new<-sub("5","2010a", census.new, fixed=TRUE)
census.new<-sub("8","2011b", census.new, fixed=TRUE)
census.new<-sub("10","2012a", census.new, fixed=TRUE)
census.new<-sub("11","2012b", census.new, fixed=TRUE)
census.new<-sub("12","2013a", census.new, fixed=TRUE)
census.new<-sub("13","2013b", census.new, fixed=TRUE)
table(census.new)
```

The resulting table is:

```
2002020202013babbb    2009a     2009b     202013ba00202012bbb    202013ba009a
              6268     3129      3129                    3129            3129

20202013baa         20202013bab      2020202013baaa   2020202013babb
       3129                3129                3129             3129
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define "funky results" for us? It'd help if you'd show us what you were expecting to result to be.

Comment: What does `census.new` look like before you amend it - can you post an example please.

Comment: Taking a punt on what your data looks like: you could add labels after changing your variable to a factor ie `factor(census.new, levels=c(2:5, 8, 10:13), labels=c("2008b", "2009a", "2009b", "2010a","2011b", "2012a", "2012b", "2013a", "2013b"))`. 
You could wrap this is `as.character` if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice to use `sub` is handicapped by its use of regular expressions: for example, it is replacing every instance of "2" by "2008b", so "2012" becomes "2008b012008b". Since you subsequently look for other (similar) strings, it cascades (snow-balls) quickly. As an example:

```
gsub('2', '2008b', c('2', '22'), fixed = TRUE)
## [1] "2008b"      "2008b2008b"
```

There are several ways around it, some more elegant than others. First, I'll generate some unique data, since I don't know exactly how yours looks:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- sample(as.character(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13)),
              size = 31300, replace = TRUE)
table(dat)
## dat
##    2    3    4    5    8   10   11   12   13 
## 3577 3573 3275 3499 3453 3481 3487 3439 3516
```

#### `sub` with regular expressions

This is by far *not* the best or optimal solution. If you want/need to continue down the road of using `sub` (or `gsub`), you should read up on [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (many many more websites and tutorials exist for regexps).

```
dat1 <- sub('^2$', '2008b', dat)
dat1 <- sub('^3$', '2009a', dat1)
dat1 <- sub('^4$', '2009b', dat1)
dat1 <- sub('^5$', '2010a', dat1)
dat1 <- sub('^8$', '2011b', dat1)
dat1 <- sub('^10$', '2012a', dat1)
dat1 <- sub('^11$', '2012b', dat1)
dat1 <- sub('^12$', '2013a', dat1)
dat1 <- sub('^13$', '2013b', dat1)
table(dat1)
## dat1
## 2008b 2009a 2009b 2010a 2010b 2012a 2012b 2013a 2013b 
##  3577  3573  3275  3499  3453  3481  3487  3439  3516
```

You can nest these (`sub('^2$', '2008b', sub('^3$', '2009a', dat))`), but it doesn't make it more readable or extensible. It's ugly, too (IMHO).

#### car::recode

This function is meant for (what I'm inferring is) your purpose.

```
library(car)
dat2 <- recode(dat, "
    2 = '2008b'; 3 = '2009a'; 4 = '2009b';
    5 = '2010a'; 8 = '2011b'; 10 = '2012a';
    11 = '2012b'; 12 = '2013a'; 13 = '2013b'")
table(dat2)
## dat2
## 2008b 2009a 2009b 2010a 2011b 2012a 2012b 2013a 2013b 
##  3577  3573  3275  3499  3453  3481  3487  3439  3516 
identical(dat1, dat2)
## [1] TRUE
```

#### Relative Performance

And the performance of `car::recode` isn't bad:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  re = {
    dat1 <- sub('^2$', '2008b', dat)
    dat1 <- sub('^3$', '2009a', dat1)
    dat1 <- sub('^4$', '2009b', dat1)
    dat1 <- sub('^5$', '2010a', dat1)
    dat1 <- sub('^8$', '2011b', dat1)
    dat1 <- sub('^10$', '2012a', dat1)
    dat1 <- sub('^11$', '2012b', dat1)
    dat1 <- sub('^12$', '2013a', dat1)
    dat1 <- sub('^13$', '2013b', dat1)
  },
  car = {
    recode(dat, "
        2 = '2008b'; 3 = '2009a'; 4 = '2009b';
        5 = '2010a'; 8 = '2011b'; 10 = '2012a';
        11 = '2012b'; 12 = '2013a'; 13 = '2013b'")
  }, times = 50)
## Unit: milliseconds
##  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
##    re 74.44709 75.97057 78.10516 77.20569 78.43732 124.42665   100   b
##   car 23.21131 24.11697 26.08724 25.74997 26.25260  77.97541   100  a
```

Comment: The use of `factor`, even wrapped in `as.character` (i think) will be much faster - and importantly also more readable - imo

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've typically avoided factors, though recently I've been relearning their benefits.

Comment: this is 12x faster than recode on my laptop `key <- c("2"="2008b","3"="2009a","4"="2009b","5"="2010a","8"="2011b","10"="2012a","11"="2012b","12"="2013a","13"="2013b"); dat3 <- key[dat]; identical(unname(dat3), dat2) [1] TRUE`

Comment: I thought of that (and actually tried it with similar results) but found it wasn't robust to other keys. That is, if there are entries that are (accidentally) not being recoded then this will wipe them into `NA`s, won't it?

Comment: so add an ifelse `ifelse((tmp <- letters) %in% (key <- c('1' = '5')), key[tmp], tmp)`